# Find the adjoint operator of an operator on $C \left [ 0,1 \right ]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $\varphi : \left [ 0, 1 \right ] \to \left [ 0,1 \right ]$ be the continuous function. Let $A : C \left [ 0,1 \right ] \to C \left [ 0,1 \right ]$ be an operator defined by $$\left ( Af\right ) \left ( t \right ) = f \left ( \varphi \left ( t \right ) \right ) $$ for $f \in C \left [ 0,1 \right ]$. Prove that $A$ is a continuous linear operator. Determine norm of $A$ and find the adjoint operator $A^*$.

---

I proved that $A$ is continuous linear and $\left \| A \right \|=1$. I don't know  how to find the adjoint operator $A^*$ of $A$. Denote $X = C \left [ 0,1 \right ]$, we define $A^*$ by for $y^* \in X^*$ we have $A^*y^* = y^* \circ A$. Hence, for $f^* \in X^*$ we get $$\left ( A^*f^*\right ) \left ( f \right ) = \left ( f^* \circ A\right ) \left ( f \right ) = f^* \left ( Af\right ) = f^* \left ( f \circ \varphi\right ).$$ How can I keep on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $C([0,1])^*$ is the space $M([0,1])$ of Radon measures on $[0,1]$ with the total variation norm. For $\mu \in M([0,1])$ and $f \in C([0,1])$, we have 
\begin{align*}
  A^*\mu(f) &= \mu(Af)\\
            &= \int_{[0,1]} f \circ \phi\, d\mu\\
            &= \int_{[0,1]} f \,d(\phi_*\mu)\\
            &= (\phi_*\mu)(f)
\end{align*}
where $\phi_*\mu \in M([0,1])$ denotes the pushforward measure $(\phi_*\mu)(B) = \mu\bigl(\phi^{-1}[B]\bigr)$ for Borel sets $B \subseteq [0,1]$.